# Dependency Injection in Angularjs with beforeEach(inject(function(...){..}));

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, jasmine

Looking at some JS Unit Testing with Jasmine, within a describe-suite I have found the following code:

```
describe("suiteName", function() {

var $controller;

beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_) {
    $controller = _$controller_;
}));

describe(....);
describe(....);


});
```

within the inner describes, the variable `$controller` is used sometime within some spec `it` to "bind" controller fields to references:

```
$controller('controllerUniqueName', {

       controllerField1: reference1,
       controllerField2: reference2,
       ...
}
```

I assume that `inject(..)` is doing some dependency injection, injecting `_$controller_` into global variable `$controller`, and `beforeEach` is just saying to do it before each specs `it` in each describe-suite that follows.

Can someone explain how the dependency injection is resolved?

In particular, what `_$controller_` equals to for the assignment `$controller = _$controller_;`?

**EDIT 1:** if I remove the injection block, unit test fails with message `TypeError: $controller is not a function`.

**EDIT 2: ** if I change `_controller_` into `something` unit test fails with message `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $somethingProvider <- $something`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_$controller_` equals to [`$controller` service instance](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$controller).

[Underscored](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.8/src/auto/injector.js#L69) service aliases are [supported](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.8/src/auto/injector.js#L115-L117) by Angular injector to make this pattern possible:

```
var $controller;
...
$controller = _$controller_;
```

If `something` service doesn't exist in loaded modules, `[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $somethingProvider <- $something` error is thrown.